# Can one PHP cli script detect if another PHP cli script is running?

Tags: php, grep, exec, command-line-interface

Is there a reliable way in which a php cli script can detect if another php cli script is running? By running in this case, I mean it would return a row for itself if I did `ps aux | grep scriptname.php` in the command line.

This command also tends to return itself in the output however, so I'm worried that if I simply do an `exec('ps aux | grep scriptname.php',$output);` that it will return a false positive.

The script I am detecting also makes log entries, but under some conditions it sleeps for up to 5 minutes, so detecting its log entries seems a crude method of detection in this instance.

Comment: Why not use a lock file to detect multiple invocations?

Comment: I never know whether to address the question or the underlying problem.  In this case I addressed the question in my answer, but I prefer Barmar's suggestion of using a lock file.

Comment: @Barmar This isn't a multiple invocations issue, although a lock file could potentially work. In this case, I think the answer of leftclickben's answer might prove less work for me however... :)

Comment: @Barmar Thinking about it, there are reasons why the lock file method is inferior in this instance. Namely, the lock file will remain present if the script crashes, making it look like the script is still running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a slightly simpler version of leftclickben's answer. Wrapping one letter in the scriptname with `[]` saves you from having to filter out `grep`.

```
exec('ps aux | grep "[s]criptname.php"', $output);
```

Comment: Are you sure about this?  I just tried (on command line, not in PHP), `echo "foo bar" | grep bar` and then `echo "foo bar" | grep "[b]ar"` and got a hit in both cases.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @leftclickben This trick is only relevant to grepping the output of ps. Start your script, than then compare `ps aux | grep scriptname.php` with `ps aux | grep "[s]criptname.php"`.

Comment: *facepalm* Of course -- it makes it so that the `ps` command doesn't actually contain "scriptname.php" but a different string with square brackets.  I learned something -- thanks :-)  The first comment on this post has a more complete explanation: http://askubuntu.com/questions/153419/how-does-this-tricky-bracket-expression-in-grep-work

Answer (score 1):

You could use `grep -v grep` to filter out the "return itself in the output" part.  That is, it will only find `scriptname.php` where there is not also `grep` in the command:

```
exec('ps aux | grep scriptname.php | grep -v grep', $output);
```

Comment: That filters out the `grep`, but it doesn't filter out the instance of the script that's checking.

Comment: So you just look for two rows instead of one...  If there is one then it's the only one running, if there are two, then there is another one.

Comment: @Barmar The script that is checking is called something else, so it shouldn't detect itself in this case. It's a good point though if someone wants to detect if the same script is already running...